# Exporting only the artboard design from AI to EPS

Tags: adobe-illustrator, eps

I'm trying to send an AI file as an EPS file for engraving and they want only the artwork inside/on the active artboard - because I started with a file of many artboards and then separated them into 20 different files, with an individual artboard in each file but elements of the neighbouring artboards' design (text on a curve that spans several boards) also showing on the grey area around the artboard.

Exporting as EPS doesn't have the option of using artboards only like a jpeg does. Really finding it a bit odd I can't just crop the artboard!

I've tried making a rectangle and Object: Path: Divide, but this isn't doing anything.

I am a beginner with AI, would very much appreciate advice! Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do *File > Save As*. Choose *Illustrator EPS* as the file format. Enable the *Use Artboards* option, and enable the *Range* option and under that type the number of the artboard you want to save.

[image]

I tested this with a multiple artboard document, and it definitely works. Note: This may look a bit different if you are using a Mac; the screen shot here is from a Windows computer.

Comment: Thanks, Billy! I'll give that a shot.